# Text editing in specific slide of powerpoint is involuntarily disabled

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

For some reason I am not able to edit the text in one of my slides (while other slides are fine) and I suspect it has something to do with the formulas and version. I saved it as ppt and pptx, and none allows me to edit this page.

[image]

Comment: Since you're able to share the slide content via image, it should also be possible to share the slide itself (in a PPTX file on DropBox or the like). That would make an answer more likely.